# Create Braintree subscriptions via api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

According to the Braintree docs in order to create subscriptions, you’ll need to first create the customer and payment method in one call, and then use the payment method token from the result object to create the subscription.

Thus far I have implemented the first part. I have done this with a create method inside my transactions_controller.rb.

But cant figure out how to implement the second part in order to create the subscription as well.
I have tried the following, which is according to [Braintree subscription docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/ruby)

But does not complete the transaction!!

```
result = Braintree::Subscription.create(
    payment_method_token:  params[:payment_method_token],
    plan_id: params[:plan_id]
)
```

Any ideas on how to implement this???

Comment: Are the values of the token and plan pulling from your client or a result object?  What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Would you mind writing into Braintree Support so we can take a closer look by locating your Sandbox account?  support@braintreepayments.com

Comment: @ThinkAboutIt...trying to pull form a customer. I have a create method in my transaction controller that creates the transaction.sale the costumer along the payment token of the costumer. It returns no errors.... It just won't finish the transaction. I already did, I'm waiting for the reply from Braintree support!!!